# How to create Struct methods and use them in Rust

Tags: rust, methods, static-methods, ownership

I am relatively new to the Rust Programming Language. And I was learning about Struct and Enums. I created a program to store the day of the week and see if it is a weekend or not as a test program. The code goes as follows:

```rs
#[derive(Debug)]
enum DaysOfTheWeekNames {
    Friday,
    Saturday,
    Sunday,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Weekday {
    day: DaysOfTheWeekNames,
    weekend: bool,
}

impl Weekday {
    fn isWeekend(day: DaysOfTheWeekNames) -> bool {
        match day {
            DaysOfTheWeekNames::Saturday => false,
            DaysOfTheWeekNames::Sunday => false,
            other => true,
        }
    }
    
    fn new_day(day: DaysOfTheWeekNames) -> Self {
        Self { day, weekend: Weekday::isWeekend(day) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let today = Weekday::new_day(DaysOfTheWeekNames::Saturday);
    println!("Today: {:#?}", today);
}
```

So my objective here is to create a struct called Weekday, and want to initialize it using the method called new_day() to which I only pass in the name of the weekday. This function should call the isWeekend() method to find if it is a weekend or not.
But the above code is throwing an error as expected, as the ownership of the variable `name` is moved to the isWeekend function and not transferred back. So what is the ideal way to write such a use case, and how should we resolve this?

The error, I see is the following:

```bash
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `day`
   --> src/main.rs:115:50
    |
114 |     fn new(day: DaysOfTheWeek) -> Self {
    |            --- move occurs because `day` has type `DaysOfTheWeek`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
115 |         Self { day, weekend: Weekday::is_weekend(day) }
    |                --- value moved here              ^^^ value used here after move
```

Comment: Pass `day` as a [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html) or [`#[derive(Copy)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-03-derivable-traits.html#clone-and-copy-for-duplicating-values) on `DaysOfTheWeekNames`

Comment: Still cannot resolve the issue. Can you please help write the code snippet? I am new to the language.

Comment: Do you mean that `fn isWeekend(day: &DaysOfTheWeekNames)` did not work?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this.
Explanation: As isWeekend is a struct method, we shouldn't pass struct fields of an instance, which we are doing above (i.e. day). To resolve this, we have to copy or clone the day param, and then pass it to the isWeekend() function.

Code:

```rs
#[derive(Debug)]
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
enum DaysOfTheWeekNames {
    Friday,
    Saturday,
    Sunday,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Weekday {
    day: DaysOfTheWeekNames,
    weekend: bool,
}

impl Weekday {
    fn is_weekend(day: DaysOfTheWeekNames) -> bool {
        match day {
            DaysOfTheWeekNames::Saturday => true,
            DaysOfTheWeekNames::Sunday => true,
            _ => false,
        }
    }
    
    fn new_day(day: DaysOfTheWeekNames) -> Self {
        Self { day, weekend: Weekday::is_weekend(day.clone()) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let today = Weekday::new_day(DaysOfTheWeekNames::Saturday);
    println!("Today: {:#?}", today);
}
```

Comment: Your code still compiles if you replace `day.clone()` with just `day`.

Comment: Oh, so the only requirement was ```#[derive(Clone, Copy)]```